# Finding correct instance of class and calling its method. C#

Tags: c#

I am developing a trading application which involves subscribing to quotes(ticks) for many symbols and running an algorithm on the incoming ticks. I have a Strategy Base Class and Algo Class which inherits from it.

```
public abstract class Strategy
{
    ...
    public int ID {get; set;}    
}


public class Algo : Strategy
{
   public void OnTick(Tick t) { // algo here }

}
```

I create an instance of Algo Class for each symbol that is traded and keep a List for all created instances each with a unique ID

```
Dictionary<Algo, string> dicOfStrategies = new ...;   

Foreach(Symbol sym in listOfSymbols) //many symbols
{
    Algo a = new Algo();
    dicOfStrategies.Add(a, "IBM");
}
```

On incoming tick:

```
if(Tick.Symbol == dicOfStrategies[Symbol]
{
   dicOfStrategies[algo].OnTick()
}
```

My question is, what is the most efficient way to route incoming ticks to the correct Algo instance with the same symbol ???

Do i search dicOfStrategis for every incoming tick and find an Algo instance match and call its method? ...there will be 1000's of ticks coming in from the stream that need to be processed quickly.. is there a better way ?? thanks for any help.

Comment: Use a dictionary, or any other data structure that has fast key lookup. At least, that's what I guess you mean by _"for every tick [...] find an Algo instance match"_. The code you show is hardly relevant, the question is how you match an algorithm to a tick.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @CodeCaster I match algo instance to tick based on the symbol.

Comment: There's no symbol being used in the code in your question. My previous comment implied that you'd better [edit] your question and show some relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer Your quesion :

*"What is the most efficient way to route incoming ticks to the correct Algo instance with the same symbol"*

```
Dictionary<string, Strategy>
```

> Dictionary | Best for high performance lookups.

[C#/.NET Fundamentals: Choosing the Right Collection Class](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/06/16/c.net-fundamentals-choosing-the-right-collection-class.aspx)

> The collection with the best performance is Dictionary<> and the collection with most compact footprint in SortedList<>.

[.NET Collections: Comparing Performance and memory usage](http://staticvoidmain.cognitioab.se/2013/11/28/net-collections-comparing-performance-and-memory-usage/)